# How to update a variable in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

In this code I try to Gamble on a number and whenever I get it right it gives me 1 dollar, but here I want to update the variable after the user gets the answer correct, like for example when user gets 1st answer correct he gets 1 dollar and when he gets his second answer correct he gets 2 dollar i.e +1 so, every time he gets the gamble correct the user get +1 dollar but the problem is that it doesn't go above 1 it stays on 1 dollar even after I get 10 answers correct. So, any thoughts on how to fix it

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import json

clients = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
Bot = discord.Client()

@Bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print('ready')


@clients.command()
async def Gamble(ctx, num):
  number = random.randint(1,2)
  nums = 0
  content = []
  if int(num) == number:
    nums = nums + 1
    await ctx.send("Congratulations! you won 1 dollar")
    content.append(nums)
    print(content)
    
  if int(num) != number:
    await ctx.send('Better luck next time')
    print(content)

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: `nums` and `content` are local variables. They'll be set anew every time the Gamble command is called. You could make `nums` and `content` globals, but that would share them among all the users of your bot (which I'm not sure you want)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
content = []

@bot.command()
async def Gamble(ctx, num):
    global content
    flag = False
    for i in content:
        if i[0] != ctx.author.name:
            flag = False
        else:
            flag = True
    if not flag:
        content.append([ctx.author.name, 0])
    number = random.randint(1, 2)
    if int(num) == number:
        await ctx.send("Congratulations! you won 1 dollar")
        for i in content:
            if i[0] == ctx.author.name:
                i[1] += 1
        print(content)

    elif int(num) != number:
        await ctx.send('Better luck next time')
        print(content)
```

First, I created a list in the global scope called `content`, and I added `global content` in the `Gamble` function to indicate that I'm referencing the global `content` list. Then I checked whether the person who is using the gamble command has already used it before. If the person hasn't used it before, then it will create a sub-list inside the `content` list, and it will have the username as the first element in the sub-list and the score - which is initially 0 - as the second element. Then, if the user guesses the number correctly, the code will try to find that person's username in the list and will update only that particular user's point value.

Comment: Can you explain your answer so that people can understand what was wrong and how did you fix it?

Comment: @ChaoticNebula Yep, just edited it to add an explanation.